# Putting a UIImage in a UIImageView resets the size of the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

So I have a simple app in which the user selects media from their library and the media appears in a UIImageView. This works fine, except that when the image pops up in the `UIImageView`, the `UIImageView` resizes itself to the dimensions of the image. [Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OulM.jpg). The storyboard file [is setup like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuHkg.png), with the XCode suggested constraints.

I've tried playing around with the constraints to see if I could fix it using them, but I couldn't find a solution. The only thing that sort of worked is setting the constraint `equal width` of the `UIImage` on the left-handed side to the right-handed side `UIImage`, but that also moved the UILabel.

I've tried setting the frame of the image.

```
image1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 300, 270);
image2.frame = CGRectMake(300, 62, 300, 270);
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? Did you set constraints? What is the UIImageView.contentMode set to?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you manually set an explicit width/height constraint, or both leading/trailing and top/down constraints, an imageView will resize itself to it's intrinsic content size, which in this case in the UIImage size

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I could fix it with the following constraints in the Attributes Inspector:

View Mode: Scale To Fill

Check on Autoresize Subviews.

I think it will automatically use this constraints when you set the size in the Size inspector.